# How to enforce a rule on importing path using alias by ESLint

Tags: javascript, eslint

I want to setup a rule which will replace the dependency of using (../../js/fileName.js) this kind of style while importing any file from other path.

We need to enforce a rule so where ever we put **'../../path'** it will give a linting error to change it into **'@/path/'** like this.

Is there anyone worked before with this issue? Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: Have a read of https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-plugins. I assume eslint uses ASTs (abstract syntax trees) so consider reading up on them too?